# Allow a file to only be accessed by the server

Tags: centos, .htaccess

I'm building a system which at some point utilizes viewing PDF files.

These files need to be locked down so that no one can view them outside of the system. This means the files cannot be directly accessed, and only accessed by the server to display to the user.

I have a folder `documents` which looks like this:

```
.htaccess
test.pdf
test.txt
```

In my .htaccess, I have the following:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

This effectively blocks me from accessing the file directly by going to `example.com/documents/test.pdf`

I still need the file to be viewable inside my system though, but it can't load it with the direct URL either. So I created a file right outside of my `documents` folder called `load_pdf.php`. This file looks like this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
$pdf = file_get_contents('documents/test.pdf');
echo $pdf;
```

And it works! I can embed the file like this:

```
<embed src="/load_pdf.php"></embed>
```

However, there is a problem. Anyone can load `load_pdf.php` directly in their browser, thus displaying the PDF document which isn't supposed to be accessible.

Is there any way to block `load_pdf.php` from being loaded unless it is being loaded by the server in my `<embed>` element?

Comment: You probably want some sort of authentication set up, so users have to be logged in and authorized to see the document.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, my software already has a login system. I just don't know how to stop `load_pdf.php` being loaded directly but still able to load by my system.

Comment: You need to add a check if the user is actually logged in or if they have the required permissions before delivering that file in your script. That really depends on how your login system works. Assuming you're using sessions for authentication, you'd have to wrap it in something like: if (isset($_SESSION['someVariableYouSetOnLogin'])) {}.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify IP address from you want access the files or if you have login then use particular email ID to allow viewing.

All this you can specify at start of your load_pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930914/prevent-pdf-file-from-downloading-and-printing

> Ultimately you will need to:
>
> - Create Images for each page
> - Present those to the user on the web via your own interface (html, flash etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following:-

```
<Files *test.pdf>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files *test.txt>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: You seem to have answered the "title" only, without reading the rest of the question?